# VBA Excel Populating cells based on previous existence

Tags: excel, states, vba

I haven't seen this addressed yet, but I think that might be because I don't know how to phrase my problem concisely.  Here's an example of what I'd like to try and do:

Given a column which holds state initials check output sheet if that state has been found before.  If it hasn't then populate a new cell with that state's initials and initialize the count (number of times state has been found) to one.  If the state's initials are found in a cell within the output sheet then increment the count by one.

With this, if we have a 50,000 (or however many) lined excel sheet that has states in random order (states may or may not be repeated) we will be able to create a clean table which outputs which states are in the raw data sheet and how many times they appeared.  Another way to think about this is coding a pivot table, but with less information.

There's a couple of ways that I've thought about how to complete this, I personally think none of these are very good ideas but we'll see.

Algorithm 1, all 50 states:

1. Create 50 string variables for each state, create 50 long variables for the counts
2. Loop through raw data sheet, if specific state found then increment appropriate count (this would require 50 if-else statements)
3. Output results

Overall..... terrible idea

Algorithm 2, flip-flop:

1. Don't create any variables
2. If a state is found in raw data sheet , look in output sheet to check if state has been found before
3. If state has been found before, increment cell adjacent by one
4. If state has not been found before, change next available blank cell to state initials and initialize cell adjacent to one
5. Go back to raw data sheet

Overall..... this could work, but I feel as if it would take forever, even with raw data sheets that aren't very big but it has the benefit of not wasting memory like the 50 states algorithm and less lines of code

On a side note, is it possible to access a workbook's (or worksheet's) cells without activating that workbook?  I ask because it would make the second algorithm run much quicker.

Thank you,

Jesse Smothermon

Comment: Are you allowed to sort the data?

Comment: I'm going to say no, I don't think it's too important (for now) to sort it

Comment: A pivot table seems to solve your problem in a straightforward way. Why don't you want to go for that?

Comment: @belisarius mainly so that I can follow the layout that my boss wants.  I was going to say that pivot tables have more information that I actually want (grand total) but then I found out you can delete that and add borders and such.  I think, in the end, this is going to become a PDF file and we want to have aesthetic appeal as well (I'll mess around with it a little more but right now the titles are giving me trouble).  Thanks for the comment, I'll look at pivot tables more closely

Comment: @belisarius actually with the pivot table they have a predefined title called "Row Labels".  Ideally I would need to change that to "State" according to the samples I was given (these are going to clients so they need to be relatively clear).  Because of that I think that pivot tables might not be allowed for the final product

Comment: @Jesse You can rewrite those headers. "Don't reinvent the wheel" :D

Comment: @belisarius really? I know you can rewrite the second column header but when I tried to rewrite the first column header it gives me an error saying I can't change that part of the array.... I'll look into it again, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of point that will speed up your code:

1. You don't need to active workbooks, worksheets or ranges to access them
   eg

   ```
   DIM wb as workbook  
   DIM ws as worksheet  
   DIM rng as range

   Set wb = Workbooks.OpenText(Filename:=filePath, Tab:=True) ' or Workbooks("BookName")  
   Set ws = wb.Sheets("SheetName")  
   Set rng = ws.UsedRange ' or ws.[A1:B2], or many other ways of specifying a range
   ```

You can now refer to the workbook/sheet/range like

```
rng.copy
for each  cl in rng.cells
etc
```

1. Looping through cells is *very* slow.  Much faster to copy the data to a variant array first, then loop through the array.  Also, when creating a large amount of data on a sheet, better to create it in a variant array first then copy it to the sheet in one go.

   ```
   DIM v As Variant
   v = rng
   ```

eg if rng refers to a range 10 rows by 5 columns, v becomes an array of dim 1 to 10, 1 to 5.  The 5 minutes you mention would probably be reduced to seconds at most

Answer (score 1):

```
   Sub CountStates()
     Dim shtRaw As Excel.Worksheet
     Dim r As Long, nr As Long
     Dim dict As Object
     Dim vals, t, k

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set shtRaw = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw")
    vals = Range(shtRaw.Range("C2"), _
                 shtRaw.Cells(shtRaw.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)).Value
    nr = UBound(vals, 1)

    For r = 1 To nr
        t = Trim(vals(r, 1))
        If Len(t) = 0 Then t = "Empty"
        dict(t) = dict(t) + 1
    Next r

    For Each k In dict.keys
        Debug.Print k, dict(k)
    Next k
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented my second algorithm to see how it would work.  The code is below, I did leave out little details in the actual problem to try and be more clear and get to the core problem, sorry about that.  With the code below I've added the other "parts".

Code:

```
' this number refers to the raw data sheet that has just been activated
totalRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    For iRow = 2 To totalRow
        ' These are specific to the company needs, refers to addresses
        If (ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, 2) = "BA") Then
            badAddress = badAddress + 1
        ElseIf (ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, 2) = "C") Then
            coverageNoListing = coverageNoListing + 1
        ElseIf (ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, 2) = "L") Then
            activeListing = activeListing + 1
        ElseIf (ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, 2) = "NC") Then
            noCoverageNoListing = noCoverageNoListing + 1
        ElseIf (ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, 2) = "NL") Then
            inactiveListing = inactiveListing + 1
        ElseIf (ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, 2) = "") Then
            noHit = noHit + 1
        End If
        ' Algorithm beginning
        ' If the current cell (in state column) has something in it
        If (ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, 10) <> "") Then
            ' Save value into a string variable
            tempState = ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, 10)
            ' If this is also in a billable address make variable true
            If (ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, 2) = "C") Or (ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, 2) = "L") Or (ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, 2) = "NL") Then
                boolStateBillable = True
            End If
            ' Output sheet
            BillableWorkbook.Activate
            For tRow = 2 To endOfState
                ' If the current cell is the state
                If (ActiveSheet.Cells(tRow, 9) = tempState) Then
                    ' Get the current hit count of that state
                    tempStateTotal = ActiveSheet.Cells(tRow, 12)
                    ' Increment the hit count by one
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(tRow, 12) = tempStateTotal + 1
                    ' If the address was billable then increment billable count
                    If (boolStateBillable = True) Then
                        tempStateBillable = ActiveSheet.Cells(tRow, 11)
                        ActiveSheet.Cells(tRow, 11) = tempStateBillable + 1
                    End If
                    Exit For
                ' If the tempState is unique to the column
                ElseIf (tRow = endOfState) Then
                    ' Set state, totalCount
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(tRow - 1, 9) = tempState
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(tRow - 1, 12) = 1
                    ' Increment the ending point of the column
                    endOfState = endOfState + 1
                    ' If it's billable, indicate with number
                    If (boolStateBillable = True) Then
                        tempStateBillable = ActiveSheet.Cells(tRow - 1, 11)
                        ActiveSheet.Cells(tRow - 1, 11) = tempStateBillable + 1
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        ' Activate raw data workbook
        TextFileWorkbook.Activate
        ' reset boolean
        boolStateBillable = False
    Next
```

I ran it once and it seems to have worked.  The problem is that it took roughly five minutes or so, the original code takes 0.2 (rough guess).  I think the only way to make the code perform quicker is to somehow be able to not activate the two workbooks over and over.  This means that the answer is not complete but I will edit if I figure out the rest.

*Note* I will revisit pivot tables to see if I can do everything that I need to in them, as of now it looks like there are a couple of things that I won't be able to change but I'll check

Thank you,

Jesse Smothermon

Answer (score 0):

I kept with the second algorithm.  There is the dictionary option that I forgot but I'm still not very comfortable with how it works and I generally don't understand it quite yet.  I played with the code for a bit and changed some thing up, it now works faster.

Code:

```
' In output workbook (separate sheet)
Sheets.Add.Name = "Temp_Text_File"

' Opens up raw data workbook (originally text file
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=filePath, Tab:=True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set TextFileWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
totalRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
' Copy all contents of raw data workbook
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy

BillableWorkbook.Activate

' Paste raw data into "Temp_Text_File" sheet
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Billable_PDF").Select

' Populate long variables
For iRow = 2 To totalRow
    If (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Temp_Text_File").Cells(iRow, 2) = "BA") Then
        badAddress = badAddress + 1
    ElseIf (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Temp_Text_File").Cells(iRow, 2) = "C") Then
        coverageNoListing = coverageNoListing + 1
    ElseIf (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Temp_Text_File").Cells(iRow, 2) = "L") Then
        activeListing = activeListing + 1
    ElseIf (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Temp_Text_File").Cells(iRow, 2) = "NC") Then
        noCoverageNoListing = noCoverageNoListing + 1
    ElseIf (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Temp_Text_File").Cells(iRow, 2) = "NL") Then
        inactiveListing = inactiveListing + 1
    ElseIf (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Temp_Text_File").Cells(iRow, 2) = "") Then
        noHit = noHit + 1
    End If
    If (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Temp_Text_File").Cells(iRow, 10) <> "") Then
        tempState = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Temp_Text_File").Cells(iRow, 10)
        If (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Temp_Text_File").Cells(iRow, 2) = "C") Or (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Temp_Text_File").Cells(iRow, 2) = "L") Or (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Temp_Text_File").Cells(iRow, 2) = "NL") Then
            boolStateBillable = True
        End If
        'BillableWorkbook.Activate
        For tRow = 2 To endOfState
            If (ActiveSheet.Cells(tRow, 9) = tempState) Then
                tempStateTotal = ActiveSheet.Cells(tRow, 12)
                ActiveSheet.Cells(tRow, 12) = tempStateTotal + 1
                If (boolStateBillable = True) Then
                    tempStateBillable = ActiveSheet.Cells(tRow, 11)
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(tRow, 11) = tempStateBillable + 1
                End If
                Exit For
            ElseIf (tRow = endOfState) Then
                ActiveSheet.Cells(tRow, 9) = tempState
                ActiveSheet.Cells(tRow, 12) = 1
                endOfState = endOfState + 1
                If (boolStateBillable = True) Then
                    tempStateBillable = ActiveSheet.Cells(tRow, 11)
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(tRow, 11) = tempStateBillable + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next
        'stateOneTotal = stateOneTotal + 1
        'If (ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, 2) = "C") Or (ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, 2) = "L") Or (ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, 2) = "NL") Then
        '    stateOneBillable = stateOneBillable + 1
        'End If
    'ElseIf (ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, 10) = "FL") Then
        'stateTwoTotal = stateTwoTotal + 1
        'If (ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, 2) = "C") Or (ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, 2) = "L") Or (ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, 2) = "NL") Then
        '    stateTwoBillable = stateTwoBillable + 1
        'End If
    End If
    'TextFileWorkbook.Activate
    If (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Temp_Text_File").Cells(iRow, 2) = "C") Or (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Temp_Text_File").Cells(iRow, 2) = "L") Or (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Temp_Text_File").Cells(iRow, 2) = "NL") Then
        billableCount = billableCount + 1
    End If
    boolStateBillable = False
Next

' Close raw data workbook and raw data worksheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
TextFileWorkbook.Close
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Temp_Text_File").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Thank you for the comments and suggestions.  It is very much appreciated as always.

Jesse Smothermon